# Magento API v2 filter by custom attribute

Tags: php, magento, soap

I've been looking all over the web but I can't seem to find any examples and I've tried it but failed. I am using version 2 of the api and I want to find product that filters by a customer attribute like so...

```
$filter = array(
        array(
            'key'=>'custom_attribute',
            'value'=>"463"
        )
);
$products = $client->catalogProductList($session,array(
    'filter'=>$filter
));
```

But I am getting all the products and not the specific product I am looking for. Is there anything I am doing wrong ? Is there anything  I am missing ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following code.

```
$complexFilter = array (
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'custom_attribute',
            'value' => array(
                'key' => 'eq', 
                'value' => '463'
            )
        )
    )
);
$products = $client->catalogProductList($session, $complexFilter);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. That didnt seem to work though. Threw a soap error.

Comment: I have dome the same but didn't get the response.I have attribute code 'productsizes',attribute_id is 151 and value is 5,how can I filter products with these